# How do I add a value to a TextBox that's inside an ASP:LoginView

Tags: asp.net, loginview

I have some `DropDownLists` and some `TextBoxes` on a page. Normally I use this to clear and add value to the items:

Clear control:

```
txtEventNote.Text = String.Empty
ddlHours.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Add value:

```
ddlHours.SelectedValue = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventDate")
txtEventTitle.Text = dtEvents.Rows(0)("EventHome").ToString()
```

But if I do this for items thats inside an `ASP:LoginView` I get an error because the ID's cant be found.

So my question is:

- How do I clear the `ddlSize` `DropDownList` ID and how do i add `String.Empty` to `txtEventName.Text` that's inside the `LoginView` which has an ID of "loginview2"?
- And how do I add a value to a `TextBox` and `DropDownList` inside an `LoginView` called "loginview2" where I have a `TextBox` with the ID textEventName.Text and the `DropDownList` have ID ddlSize.

If I delete the `LoginView` it's easy for me to do, but when I add the `LoginView` the ID's can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoginView` control is a container control. It can hold other ASP.NET WebForm controls. To get a reference to the controls contained within the `LoginView` control use the `FindContol` method of the `LoginView` control.

```
TextBox tb = lcLoginView.FindControl("txtEventNote") as TextBox
if (tb != null)
{
     tb.Text = "My New Value For This TextBox control";
}
```

Do the same for your `DropDownList`.

I found [In Search Of ASP.Net Controls](http://odetocode.com/articles/116.aspx) to be helpful for more about finding ASP.NET controls in other ASP.NET controls.

Comment: I see what u do for getting data, but how do i Add a value to textbox txtEventNote !?

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen - I updated my answer. tb.Text = "My New Value For This TextBox control";

Comment: Ah ok so the textbox id="txtEventNote" is also called tb, so if i use the code then tb.Text = session("myname") is working 100% as txtEventNote.Text = session("myname") bc i have giving it a extra name, Right !??

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen - That is correct. In this case the tb variable is a reference to the TextBox control located in the LoginView control.